# Why3 is unable to run prover on windows via cygwin

Tags: frama-c, why3

I am trying to use `cvc4` prover with `Frama-c wp` plugin through `Why3` on Windows environment. I have `frama-c` and `why3` installed on my system. Why3 is configured properly to include cvc4 as a prover :

```
$ why3 --list-provers
Known provers:
Alt-Ergo (0.95.2)
CVC4 (1.4)
```

I used frama-c Wp plugin to generate why3 format (.why) file corresponding to my .c file (C source file with ACSL Specifications) with following command:

```
frama-c -wp -wp-print -wp-proof-trace -wp-out C:/Users/user/temp -wp-prover cvc4 swap.c
```

The above command generate a file `swap_Why3_ide.why` in `C:/Users/user/temp/typed` directory.

When I try to prove Theories in generated `swap_Why3_ide.why` file using `why3` with `cvc4` as prover it fails with following error:

```
$ why3 prove -P cvc4 -L C:/cygwin/usr/local/share/frama-c/wp/why3 temp/typed/swap_Why3_ide.why

temp/typed/swap_Why3_ide.why VCswap_post WP : HighFailure (0.02s)
Prover exit status: exited with status 1

Prover output:
/usr/local/lib/why3/why3-cpulimit: Error: failed when launching <"/cygdrive/c/cvc4-1.4-win32-opt.exe" "--lang=smt2" "/tmp/why_29ba75_swap_Why3_ide-T-WP.smt2">
Fatal: CreateProcess failed with error 0: The operation completed successfully.
```

I performed same steps on a linux environment and `why3` was able to execute prover:

```
why3 prove -P cvc4 -L /usr/local/share/frama-c/wp/why3/ temp/typed/swap_Why3_ide.why
temp/typed/swap_Why3_ide.why VCswap_post WP : Valid (0.05s)
```

Can anyone suggest how to execute Why3 on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like no one is using why3 on Windows. But anyways, for anyone who will try to use Why3 on windows in future, here are steps I performed to run a prover on theories in a .why file:

1) On Windows, even if provers are installed, executing `why3 config --detect` will not add provers. So when executing `why3 config --detect --add-prover cvc4 path_to_executable_in_Windows_format` make sure that path to executable is in windows format( for example C:\provers\cvc4-1.4-win32-opt.exe)

If path is not in windows format, following error is thrown:

```
/usr/local/lib/why3/why3-cpulimit: Error: failed when launching <"/cygdrive/c/cvc4-1.4-win32-opt.exe" "--lang=smt2" "/tmp/why_29ba75_swap_Why3_ide-T-WP.smt2">
Fatal: CreateProcess failed with error 0: The operation completed successfully.
```

2) After setting path to provers properly, try to execute why3 as follows:

```
why3 prove -P cvc4 -L C:/cygwin/usr/local/share/frama-c/wp/why3 C:/temp/typed/swap_Why3_ide.why
```

This will throw following error:

```
C:/temp/typed/swap_Why3_ide.why VCswap_post WP : HighFailure (0.03s)
Prover exit status: exited with status 1
Prover output:
(error "Couldn't open file: /tmp/why_727ef8_swap_Why3_ide-T-WP.smt2")
why3cpulimit cpu time: 0.015625s wall time: 0.015625s
```

This error is occurring because why3 generates *.smt2 files in cygwin tmp directory (`/tmp`) and when provers are called over these files complete path to these files in not provided and prover complain that it `Couldn't open file /tmp/XX.smt2`

To fix this I had to update command executed to run prover in `.why3.conf` as following:

```
[prover]
command = "%l/why3-cpulimit %t %m -s C:/provers/cvc4-1.4-win32-opt.exe --lang=smt2 C:/cygwin%f
driver = "/usr/local/share/why3/drivers/cvc4.drv"
editor = ""
in_place = false
interactive = false
name = "CVC4"
shortcut = "cvc4"
version = "1.4"
```

Note that I changed the file format from `%f` to `C:/cygwin%f` which is windows path to `/tmp` directory